# How can we skip "a template argument" as we EXPLICIT specify "template arguments" (to move to the next)?

Tags: c++

I have created a function template 'prin()' like the following bellow - but have problem when it comes to explicitly specialize the paramters of the function.
How can I skip a template argument like the following to move to the next?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <map>

template<class T> void prinSequenceContainer (T vec){ 
    for (auto var : vec){ std::cout << var << ' ';} 
}

template < template <typename, typename, typename...> class T , typename T1, typename T2 , typename...T3 , typename T4> 
void prin( T<T1,T2,T3...> map){    
    std::vector<T1> vec;
    std::list<T2> list1;
    std::forward_list<T4> forward_list1;

    //this block is to extract the KEY value and the MAPPED value of the map into a vector and a list
    for ( auto it=map.begin() ; it !=map.end() ;   it++ ){
        vec.push_back( it->first );
        list1.push_back(it->second);
    }

    //this block is to print the values of the vector and list after all.
    prinSequenceContainer(vec);
    prinSequenceContainer(list1);
    prinSequenceContainer(forward_list1);
}

int main(){
    std::map<char , int> map1={
        {'A' , 1},
        {'B' , 2},
        {'C' , 3},
        {'D' , 4},
        {'E' , 5},
        {'F' , 6},
    };

    //Try my luck to "explicitly" specify the template parameters for the function MYSELF
    prin< std::map, char, int, T3..., int >(map1);    //FAIL = how can I skip "the gap T3..." to move the next int_[T4] without error?

    return 0;
}
```

I am very beginner and under a serious need of help, please help :) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function template accepts a template, two type parameters and a parameter pack.
Therefore when explicitly specifying their template parameters, it should look the following way:
`prin<std::map, char, int>(map1);` (parameter pack can be empty, so it is here).

As for making int double: another map has to be created or the values have to be cast while processing.
This however: `prin<std::map, char, double>(map1);` will try to call function `void prin(std::map<char,double>)` (this is what is going to be instantiated) with argument of type `std::map<char, int>` effectively causing (legit) compilation error.

Comment: thannks @alagner ! it was a great help!

Comment: Does anyone know how to skip "an argument" as we explicitly specialize "template arguments" (to move to the next) ? Like we define:  ||Template < template <typename, typename, typename...> class T , typename T1, typename T2 , typename...T3 , class T4>   
void prin( T<T1,T2,T3...> map){...} ___And then when we use it ||prin<std::map , char ,..skipT3..., int_[T4] > (map1); !?!?  . how can we skip T3 and move on specify T4? :)

Comment: @Rango long story short: not easily. What do you need that for?

Comment: Currently it's for my curiosity :D .

Comment: T4 is not in the parameter spots of the function, so the complier can NOT deduce it for us. So I need to explicitly specify it. perhaps, if I create a class template where we must always specify all of the T1,T2,T4...so I think i would come in handy in such case :D .

Answer (score 0):

Answer my own question after a few days reading Creference for a few days :D (for whoever needed)

- If there is a pack expansion ( ...Tx) it must be at the end. It's conventional rule for good. So that we don't have to skip anything
- And indeed we need only one "...Tx" for any template, there is no need to define a SECOND "...Tx" (and also it's not allowed :D ) because: 
  (1) ...Tx is already the MOST generic type (it fits any type, any number of types) 
  (2) We can re-use it anywhere and for any times we want, for example:

```
template< template<class, class...> class T, class T1, class T2, class...Tx>
void function( T<T1, Tx...> object1 , T<T2, Tx...> object2);
```